# Disable info popups on YouTube app ("ⓘ")

Tags: youtube, ads, content-filter

When viewing videos with the YouTube app, constant info message popups during playback shows. Videos that show those info popups show a white circle with the letter 'i'.

Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: AFAIK, YouTube app provides very little settings outside of video playback, and the info popup might be enforced by YouTube itself. Probably the only choice is to go for 3rd-party YouTube player apps.

Comment: By info-pops are you referring to ads or other annotations related to video?

Comment: I wonder if some clever developer might be able to modify the YouTube app's .apk file in order to do what you want.

Comment: Seems like these sliding info panels have just made an unwelcome comeback in the last few weeks. I don't remember seeing these before and now one pops up every couple of minutes during video playback. I don't understand who makes the final call on such self-evidently intrusive screen junk. It's almost as if watching videos is now a side-effect of visiting youtube. AdTube.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using the official YouTube app, I'm unaware of any way to do what you want.

## Your options

The best workaround is to use a different app to watch YouTube.

- Lately, I've been using [m.youtube.com](https://m.youtube.com) inside **Google Chrome**. In my experience, m.youtube.com is unable to display info popups. (It's also unable to display [end cards](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6388789).) Alternatively, you can use:

  - **another web browser**, such as Firefox for Android; or
  - any of the numerous dedicated **third-party YouTube clients** available in the Google Play store.

## Bonus tip

Firefox for Android lets you install extensions, such as uBlock Origin.  If you do install uBlock Origin, know that it includes an '[element picker](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Element-picker)' feature.  This feature lets you hide selected parts of your favorite websites.  For example, you can use it to hide all recommendations, or all comments, on the YouTube website.